# Format string using regex to remove non space whitespace characters

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently trying to scrape a website for some information but am running into some issues.

I currently have a bs4.element.Tag element with some html and text in it, and when I do "variable.text", I get the following text:

`\n\nUlmstead Club\n\t\t\t\t\t911 Lynch Dr\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\tArnold, Maryland\t\t\t\t\t 21012\n\t\t\t\t\tUnited States\n(410) 757-9836 \n\n Get directions\n\n Favorite court \n\n\n\nTennis Court Details\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tLocation type:\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tClub\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMatches played here:\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t0\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t`

What I want is to get rid of all the white space characters (`\n` and `\t`) to get the relevant information in a list or any iterable form.

I've tried a bunch of regex commands already, but the one that got me closest to my goal was: `re.split('[\t\n]',variable.text)`, I got the following:

```
['',
 '',
 'Ulmstead Club',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '911 Lynch Dr',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 'Arnold, Maryland',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
```

I've cut off a lot of the output to save some space.

I'm super lost and any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: All whitespace except spaces: find  `[^\S ]+` replace with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting on `[\t\n]+`:

```
re.split('[\t\n]+', variable.text.strip())
```

This would seem to work as it would eliminate the empty string entries in the output array.

Comment: Don't know if it is a problem of Python 3.x, but the result I got from the split resulted in an empty string at first and last position inside the list

Comment: @PabloAlvarez Call `strip` on the input string, to remove leading and trailing whitespace.  I did not consider this when answering.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that, this simple expression might be also helpful,

```
(?:\\n|\\t)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4brnMe/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(?:\\n|\\t)"

test_str = "\\n\\nUlmstead Club\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t911 Lynch Dr\\n\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\tArnold, Maryland\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t 21012\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\tUnited States\\n(410) 757-9836 \\n\\n Get directions\\n\\n Favorite court \\n\\n\\n\\nTennis Court Details\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\tLocation type:\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\n\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\tClub\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\n\\n\\n\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\tMatches played here:\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\n\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t0\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\n\\n\\n\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t"

subst = ""

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Comment: `(?:\\n|\\t)` to a regex engine tells it to look for the literal characters `\n` and `\t`

Comment: Also, this would result in a single string with no separators at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `string.replace()` function to get rid of the \n and \t, no really needing a regular expression to do so (I have replaced the \n and \t with 2 whitespaces for the next step):

```
variable.text = variable.text.replace("\n","  ")
variable.text = variable.text.replace("\t","  ")
```

if you want then to split your data into a list, you could split it through whitespaces, and use `remove()` to delete any extra empty strings in the list *(note that I am not 100% sure of how you want your data separated, I have just made the solution that fitted my logic of how it should be split)* :

```
result = re.split("[\s]\s+",variable.text)
while ('' in result):
    result.remove('')
```

Here is the full code example:

```
import re    

teststring ="\n\nUlmstead Club\n\t\t\t\t\t911 Lynch Dr\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\tArnold, Maryland\t\t\t\t\t 21012\n\t\t\t\t\tUnited States\n(410) 757-9836 \n\n Get directions\n\n Favorite court \n\n\n\nTennis Court Details\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tLocation type:\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tClub\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMatches played here:\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t0\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"

teststring = teststring.replace("\n","  ")
teststring = teststring.replace("\t","  ")

#split any fields with more than 1 whitespace between them
result = re.split("[\s]\s+",teststring)

#remove any empty string fields of the list
while ('' in result):
    result.remove('')

print(result)
```

Result is:

```
['Ulmstead Club', '911 Lynch Dr', 'Arnold, Maryland', '21012', 'United States', '(410) 757-9836', 'Get directions', 'Favorite court', 'Tennis Court Details', 'Location type:', 'Club', 'Matches played here:', '0']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would run 2 regex on the string starting with 1 then 2

1. Find `\s*(?:\r?\n)\s*`
   Replace `\n`

https://regex101.com/r/EGTyKB/1

2. Find `[ ]*\t+[ ]*`
   Replace `\t`

https://regex101.com/r/XIyi44/1

This clears out all the whitespace cruft and turns it into
a readable block of text.

```
Ulmstead Club
911 Lynch Dr
Arnold, Maryland 21012
United States
(410) 757-9836
Get directions
Favorite court
Tennis Court Details
Location type:
Club
Matches played here:
0
```